# cut the part of the string in java

Tags: java, string, usb

```
String DeviceName = "Black USB (H:)";
```

How to separate the "Black USB"  and remove (H:) from the string in JAVA, which I need to pass on further in method in other class.

Comment: Is this a pattern, or just for this string?

Answer (score 7):

There's no need to use regular expressions or splitting operations for such a simple problem, that would be overkill. Try this:

```
String name = deviceName.substring(0, deviceName.indexOf('(')-1);
```

It's the simplest way, and it works for the general case of a device name in windows - without knowing beforehand the actual name of the device.

Comment: @rohitarora Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Answer (score 1):

Lot of ways to achieve what you want (regex, StringTokenizer, String's split()). One would be:

```
String[] splitArray = deviceName.split("Black USB");
```

Assuming, it is just for this String ("Black USB" can be hardcoded).

Answer (score 1):

I would use regexps. Modify it a bit if you need to catch a different format:

```
String s = "Black USB (H:)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*) \\((.*)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matches(s);
if (m.matches()) { 
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
   System.out.println(m.group(2));
} else { 
   System.out.prinln("No match");
}
```

Comment: make the regex `"^(.*)\s?\\((.*)\\)$` and it will be about as generic as it can get.